# Как задать значение атрибута SimpleXML для узла с дефисом в имени

Tags: php, simplexml

Есть объект SimpleXML
Часть его дампа, элемент на верхнем уровне текущего узла.

```
  ["delivery-options"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#1123 (1) refcount(1){
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#1124 (1) refcount(1){
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(2) refcount(1){
        ["cost"]=>
        string(1) "0" refcount(1)
        ["days"]=>
        string(1) "0" refcount(1)
      }
    }
  }
```

Основная проблема для начала это то что я не могу написать так.

```
$offer->delivery-options
```

Как обращаться к таким узлам?

Задача присвоить например атрибуту `cost` какое то значение.

```
PHP 5.4.3
```

Comment: а так можете `$offer->{'delivery-options}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сходу приходит в голову вот такой вариант:

```
$xmlstr = "<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>";
$xmlstr .= <<<XML
<top>
 <element-with-defis>
  <subelement>value</subelement>
 </element-with-defis>
</top>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$prop = 'element-with-defis';
var_dump($xml);
var_dump($xml->$prop);
$xml->$prop->addAttribute('cost', '5');
var_dump($xml);
```

Работает это так:

```
$ php test.php 
class SimpleXMLElement#1 (1) {
  public $element-with-defis =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#2 (1) {
    public $subelement =>
    string(5) "value"
  }
}
class SimpleXMLElement#2 (1) {
  public $subelement =>
  string(5) "value"
}
class SimpleXMLElement#1 (1) {
  public $element-with-defis =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#2 (2) {
    public $@attributes =>
    array(1) {
      'cost' =>
      string(1) "5"
    }
    public $subelement =>
    string(5) "value"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ок с доступом к узлу понятно а вот присвоение а не добавление атрибута с полным повторением структуры тут не понимаю.

Comment: `$prop = 'delivery-options';
$xml->$prop->attributes()->cost = '5';`

Имели ввиду это?

Comment: Уже не актуально, просто вы читаете между строк... Если внимательно посмотреть на дамп в вопросе то явно видно что структура и вложенность отличается от вашего ответа, а сохранение структуры в ответе в данном случае было важно.

Answer (score 1):

```
$offer->{'delivery-options'}
```